# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance

Tags: wildfly-8, hazelcast

I am trying to include hazelcast jars in Wildfly-8.2.1-Final. I have done following steps.

1. Included all jars to wildfly_Home\modules\system\layers\base\com\hazelcast\main
2. Included module.xml inside the main folder.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.hazelcast">
   <resources>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-all-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-client-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-cloud-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-hibernate-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-spring-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-wm-2.2.jar"/>
   <resource-root path="hazelcast-ra-2.2.rar"/>
   </resources>
   <dependencies>
   <module name="asm.asm"/>
   <module name="javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag"/>
   <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV"/>
   </dependencies>
   </module>`
3. Included a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file inside META-INF of my .ear file. This ear file includes two other war sub-deployments.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
   <dependencies>
   <module name="com.hazelcast"/>
   </dependencies>
   </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>`

But when I trying to deploy ear files, I am getting following error.

`2015-10-29 12:00:25,225 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear"."ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear"."ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.ericsson.ssp.ws.PublishImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear.ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance from [Module "deployment.ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear.ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    ... 15 more
2015-10-29 12:00:25,345 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-2) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([{"deployment" => "ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear"}]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.ericsson.ssp.ws.PublishImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear.ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance from [Module \"deployment.ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear.ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
2015-10-29 12:00:25,345 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment \"ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.ericsson.ssp.ws.PublishImpl with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear.ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance from [Module \"deployment.ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear.ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
2015-10-29 12:00:25,375 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
2015-10-29 12:00:25,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war) in 106ms
2015-10-29 12:00:29,884 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: ssp-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war) in 4537ms
2015-10-29 12:00:29,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear (runtime-name: ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear) in 4597ms
2015-10-29 12:00:29,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (XNIO-1 task-2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module."ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT"."ssp-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear"."ssp-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."ssp-ear-admin-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.ear"."ssp-ws-notification-1.7.6-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE`

Am I missing something? Please, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace? Th error doesn't say much to me and I'm a Hazelcast engineer.

Comment: Hi @pveentjer , Thanks for the quick response. My error has changed a bit. I have modified issue as per the stacktrace. Please have a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently the HazelcastInstance class can't be found. But I don't know the reason; I have no experience with wildfly.

However I see the following:

```
<resource-root path="hazelcast-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-all-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-client-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-cloud-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-hibernate-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-spring-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-wm-2.2.jar"/>
<resource-root path="hazelcast-ra-2.2.rar"/>
```

AFAIK you can get rid of all dependencies apart from 'all' since that includes all others.